# Check value of form that has Placeholder PHP

Tags: php, html, post

I would like to achieve this goal:

If the input in an form contains the standard value of the placeholder.
In this case "did not receive invitation...",
Then an variable which contains the input value may also be : "did not receive invitation..."

BUT if the user overwrites the placeholder and gives in an email-address,
That same variable must become that email-address.

This is my form: 
it's in dutch...sorry for that

```
<label for="invite">Email contact invitation</label>
    <input name="invite" type="text" id="invite" style="width:200px"
             placeholder="did not receive invitation..."/><br/>
```

this is my PHP:

```
if (!empty($_GET['invite'])) {
   $invitation = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'invite');
} else {
    $invitation = "did not receive invitation...";  
}
```

For some reason my output is always :

> did not receive invitation...

Even if I fill in an email address..

Any suggestions ?

Edit...
Full form Code:

```
<form class="cmxform" id="Offerteform" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div>

    <label for="Uitnodiging">Email contact uitnodiging</label>
    <input name="Uitnodiging" type="text" id="Uitnodiging" style="width:200px" placeholder="Geen uitnodiging ontvangen..." />
    <br/>

    <label for="Soort_Werken">Soort Werken</label>
    <select name="Soort Werken" id="Soort_Werken" style="width:200px" title="Selecteer iets AUB!" required>
      <option selected="selected" value="">Selecteer...</option>
      <option value="algemene schoonmaak">algemene schoonmaak</option>
      <option value="industriële reiniging">industriële reiniging</option>
      <option value="petrochemische reiniging">petrochemische reiniging</option>
      <option value="nucleaire reiniging">nucleaire reiniging</option>
      <option value="oplevering werkzaamheden">oplevering werkzaamheden</option>
      <option value="werken in onderaanneming">werken in onderaanneming</option>
      <option value="calamiteiten">calamiteiten</option>
      <option value="schoonmaak voertuigen">schoonmaak voertuigen</option>
      <option value="ruitenwassen">ruitenwassen</option>
      <option value="andere">andere</option>
    </select>
    <br/>


    <label for="Frequentie">Frequentie</label>
    <select name="Frequentie" id="Frequentie" style="width:200px" title="Selecteer iets AUB!" required>
      <option selected="selected" value="">Selecteer...</option>
      <option value="eenmalig">eenmalig</option>
      <option value="dagelijks">dagelijks</option>
      <option value="wekelijks">wekelijks</option>
      <option value="maandelijks">maandelijks</option>
      <option value="anders">anders</option>
    </select>
    <br/>


    <label for="Oppervlakte">Oppervlakte in m²</label>
    <input name="Oppervlakte" type="text" id="Oppervlakte" style="width:200px" />
    <br/>


    <label for="Bedrijfsnaam">Bedrijfsnaam</label>
    <input name="Bedrijfsnaam" type="text" id="Bedrijfsnaam" style="width:200px" />
    <br/>


    <label for="Contactpersoon_achternaam">Contactpersoon Naam</label>
    <input name="Contactpersoon_achternaam" type="text" id="Contactpersoon_achternaam" style="width:200px" />
    <br/>

    <label for="Contactpersoon_voornaam">Contactpersoon Voornaam</label>
    <input name="Contactpersoon_voornaam" type="text" id="Contactpersoon_voornaam" style="width:200px" />
    <br/>


    <label for="Functie">Functie</label>
    <input name="Functie" type="text" id="Functie" style="width:200px" />
    <br/>


    <label for="Telefoon">Telefoon</label>
    <input name="Telefoon" type="text" id="Telefoon" style="width:200px" />
    <br/>


    <label for="email">E-mail</label>
    <input name="email" type="email" id="email" style="width:200px" />
    <br/>
    <br/>

    <label for="Werkzaamheden">Type Werkzaamheden</label>

    <br/>


    <br/>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="Werkzaamheden[]" value="kantoor onderhoud" id="Werkzaamheden_0" required/>kantoor onderhoud</label>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="Werkzaamheden[]" value="tapijtreiniging" id="Werkzaamheden_1" />tapijtreiniging
    </label>
    <br/>

    <label>

      <input type="checkbox" name="Werkzaamheden[]" value="stoomreiniging" id="Werkzaamheden_2" />stoomreiniging
    </label>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="Werkzaamheden[]" value="hogedrukreiniging" id="Werkzaamheden_3" />hogedrukreiniging
    </label>
    <br />
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="Werkzaamheden[]" value="vloer onderhoud" id="Werkzaamheden_4" />vloer onderhoud</label>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="Werkzaamheden[]" value="sanitair onderhoud" id="Werkzaamheden_5" />sanitair onderhoud</label>
    <br />
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="Werkzaamheden[]" value="gevelreiniging" id="Werkzaamheden_6" />gevelreiniging
    </label>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="Werkzaamheden[]" value="hoogwerker" id="Werkzaamheden_7" />hoogwerker
    </label>
    <br />
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="Werkzaamheden[]" value="andere" id="Werkzaamheden_8" />andere
    </label>
    <br/>
    <br/>

    <label for="Werkzaamheden" class="error1">Selecteer type AUB.</label>

    <br/>
    <br/>

    <div id="Opmerking">
      <label for="opmerkingen">Opmerkingen</label>

      <textarea name="opmerkingen" id="opmerkingen" cols="50" rows="9" style="width:350px"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div id="knoppen">

      <input name="send" type="submit" class="submit2" id="send" value="verzenden" />
      <input name="reset" type="reset" class="submit2" id="reset" value="wissen" />
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: can you show your form full code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your form method is `POST` so you need to check post values using `$_POST`

just replace

```
if (!empty($_GET['invite'])){
```

to

```
if (!empty($_POST['invite'])){
```

**Also you have wrong code above for invite input if you check your full form code there is not any invite input field** so use **email** instead of `invite` like

```
if (!empty($_POST['email'])){
```

Comment: that didn't fix it :( EDIT !! I changed the wrong IF statement! It works !! thanx !! PROBLEM SOLVED

Comment: I know that there is not an invite field. I quickly translate the word to english. The dutch word for invite is "Uitnodiging". It was to not confuse english people on here. But I guess I made it worse hehe. Its working now Thanx man!

Answer (score 0):

Try with the below code

```
if (isset($_POST['invite'])){
$invitation = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'invite');
}
else{
$invitation = "did not receive invitation...";  
}
```

Comment: I don't think isset will work. Cause isset checks if the variable Exists. I don't want to check if it exists cause it clearly does. I want to check the value of it. So i'll need 'empty'